# Header and Footer Menu not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I stuck up with small problem (Used Technology MVC3.0, EntityFramework, Code First, VS2010)

We have two roles Category and Product 
   - Here we have a controller folder to each role 
   - In Category Folder we have Controller, View, Shared, Model folders
   - In Product also we have Controller, View, Shared, Model folders.
The problem starts here
   - In the Category role there is a Home in View Folder consists of 4 .cshtml files.
While we try to read these 4 .cshtml files in Product role its showing the error "resource not found" and its showing the path /Products/Home. Here Product role didnt have the Home in View folder but Category consists the Home Folder in View Folder.

Can any one help on this
Below is the code I wrote in Product folder - Shared Folder - _layout.cshtml

```
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("FAQs", "FAQs", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Help", "Help", "Home")</li>
```

and the Category folder consists of HomeController.cs file.

Thanks In Advance
Bhanu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this in your Global.asax...

```
routes.MapRoute("Category",
                "Category/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: if the home folder out of category folder and we want to call the items in Product folder then how to apply. Can you please advise

Comment: routes.MapRoute("Default",
               "Default/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               new { controller = "Home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });